# File get content not working

Tags: magento-2.1

magento 2 file get content not working 
please help

Comment: It clearly says you are trying to access the methods directly of that class. As its an abstract class you cant directly access it. You need to extend it to use those classes.

Answer (score 2):

From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php):

> PHP 5 introduces abstract classes and methods. Classes defined as abstract may not be instantiated, and any class that contains at least one abstract method must also be abstract. Methods defined as abstract simply declare the method's signature - they cannot define the implementation.

I think you are trying to make a controller and not an abstract controller and as such removing the abstract class keyword will solve your issue.